# Transient service in a blazor server project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have create a Service in a blazor server project.

I have declared this way in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

I have put some log in service constructor:

```
class MyService: IMyService
{
    public MyService()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Constructor");
    }

    public ~MyService()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Destructor");
    }
}
```

I am injecting this service on a blazor page:

```
@page "/"
@inject IMyService service
```

I do not understand:

- If i load one page, constructor is called 2 times.
- If i load a second page in my browser, constructor is called 2 times again. I was thinking constructor was called once per page. Why is there a second instance ?
- Destructor is NEVER called. What should i do to clean up memory ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have server prerendering enabled?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> If i load one page, constructor is called 2 times.

If this is the first page of the application in Server mode then yes it will.  The server render and then the final client side render.

> If i load a second page in my browser, constructor is called 2 times again. I was thinking constructor was called once per page. Why is there a second instance ?

Are you reloading the application?  Two loads would suggest you are?

> Destructor is NEVER called. What should i do to clean up memory ?

I think the Service container deals with objects with destructors the same as classes implementing `IDispose`: it hangs on to a reference to the object until the service container itself is destroyed.  Thus the GC doesn't destroy any transient objects till the `Scoped` service container is destroyed by the GC.

You need to look at `OwningComponentBase` to deal with transient services that need destructors/implement `IDispose`.  The service container gets destroyed when the component goes out of scope  This is a common memory leak issue with  DbContexts and transient services.

Can anyone definitively confirm/refute this?